# Alter cassandra column family primary key using cassandra-cli or CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-cli, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra 1.2.5. After creating a column family in Cassandra using cassandra-cli, is it possible to modify the primary key on the column family using either cassandra-cli or CQL?

Specifically, I currently have the following table (from CQL):

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
  key blob,
  column1 blob,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
);
```

I would like the table to be as follows, without having to drop and recreate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
  key blob,
  column1 blob,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (key)
);
```

Is this possible through either cassandra-cli or CQL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The primary keys directly determine how and where cassandra stores the data contained in a table (column family). The primary key consists of partition key and clustering key (optional).

> The partition key determines which node stores the data. It is responsible for data distribution across the nodes. The additional columns determine per-partition clustering (see [compound key documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html)).

So changing the primary key will always require all data to be migrated. I do not think that either cqlsh or cassandra-cli have a command for this (as of 2015)..